# WPF bind to ancestor from UserControl that is added from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatrigger

I have a user control which I use to dynamically populate a ListBox from code behind. I want the colors of an icon reversed when the parent ListBoxItem is selected.

However the datatrigger doesn't work. I get the following error message: "Source not found: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem', AncestorLevel='1'"

However, I got 2 cases in which the DataTrigger (as below) starts working.

1. If I hard code the user control in my XAML. Which is not an option.
2. If I change something about the Style (e.g. the default value from true and back to false). So basically if I force the style to be reevaluated.

So I think I know what is happening, but I don't know what to do about it: I create a new instance of the UserControl in code behinde and the Style and DataTrigger are immediately evaluated and throw an error (which makes sense, since it is not yet added to the VisualTree and therefore there is no ancestor to be found).

Heres the content of my user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FontAwesomeIconInvertedColorOnSelection" TargetType="fonts:FontAwesomeIcon">
        <Setter Property="ReverseColors" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                            Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ReverseColors" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <fonts:FontAwesomeIcon 
        Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeIconInvertedColorOnSelection}" />
</Grid>
```

Can I somehow force the Style to be reevaluate upon UserControl.Loaded? Or do you maybe have another suggestion on how to get my desired behviour?

Comment: The UserControl should not declare that DataTrigger Binding at all, since it creates an unnecessary dependency. Why should the control always only be used in a ListBoxItem? Instead, let your UserControl expose its own `IsSelected` property, to which you bind the DataTrigger (or a regular Trigger), and which is bound in a ListBox's ItemTemplate where you use the control.

Comment: From what you are showing one may even argue why there is a UserControl at all, instead of a simple DataTemplate resource.

Comment: I omitted some code to make it less cluttered. Theres a little more to it than is shown above. Thank you for your suggestion. That makes perfect sense!
However, if I use my UserControl in the ItemTemplate, then the DataContext in my UserControl is automatically the underlying data object. How can I then bind to the IsSelected property in my UserControl?

Comment: I suppose a RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyUserControl} should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserControl should expose an appropriate property, e.g. `IsSelected` that you would bind to the ListBoxItem's IsSelected property in the DataTemplate.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyIconControl
                IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the UserControl's XAML, the property would be bound by another RelativeSource Binding:

```
<Grid>
    <fonts:FontAwesomeIcon
        ReverseColors="{Binding IsSelected,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not a Solution to the question (especially considering @Clemens answer).
Consider this as an extended comment.

The issue you raised is not related to the Style and Binding in the DataTrigger.

Here's a simple example to show apply your styling without using a custom FontAwesomeIcon:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="StyleInUserControl.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StyleInUserControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FontAwesomeIconInvertedColorOnSelection" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                            Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource FontAwesomeIconInvertedColorOnSelection}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="StyleInUserControl.MyUCExamleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyUCExamleWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
    public partial class MyUCExamleWindow : Window
    {
        public MyUCExamleWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listBox.Items.Add(new MyUserControl() { DataContext = "First" });
            listBox.Items.Add(new MyUserControl() { DataContext = "Second" });
            listBox.Items.Add(new MyUserControl() { DataContext = "Third" });
            listBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
```

This example works great without any binding errors.

From this we can conclude that the cause of your problem lies not in the code that you showed.
It is found either in the implementation code for "fonts: FontAwesomeIcon" or in the initialization code for the ListBox in the Window.
But you did not show these codes.

As for the implementation of UserControl itself, it consists of only one UI element and a style for it, and it is completely unclear why to declare such a UserControl.

I also completely agree with Clement.
UserControl "does not know" where, within which container it will be used.
And the "FindAncestor" binding in Style looks very crooked and wrong.
If you need some external data that can be determined only by the place of application of the UserControl, then it is better to declare a property for them in the UserControl and then set a value or a binding to this property.